# Is a bad practice to use accent in python class name?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm developing an app in Python3 and need to create a class that represents a diary. Well, I want to name it in my language, and it has an accent. Is it a bad practice? Will I have problems because of this character?

`class Diário(Base):
    pass`

Comment: No, it does not matter, although it may frustrate other coders with English keyboards ;)

Comment: @ArthurJulião It matters, because it will throw a **Syntax Error**

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres: Not in Python 3 it won't.

Comment: Still bad practice though hehe :)

Comment: Why do you think that @PauloBu?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah I know, But around the 80% of python programmers use Python 2.x

Comment: Same reason @cdonts explained in his answer. Not to tell the hell of an encoding problem you'll be getting into if you're not careful, or when you distribute your source to the community.

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres: So? This question is tagged `[python-3.x]`.

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres: because that's best Stack Overflow practice; tag with `[python]` always, add a version tag if the question is version specific.

Comment: @ArthurJulião: Why bother anyways? Why need to have accents in mind when programming? It's not like an orthography teacher is gonna review your source, and is one thing less to worry about, just saying.

Comment: @PauloBu *I* will review my source code and will be either actively confused or at least annoyed if the perfectly normal word "Käse" is turned into "Kase" or "Kaese", neither of which is a German word or a common alternative spelling for a German word. Source code is not natural language, but readable source code uses words from natural languages, and that has many benefits. These benefits are diminished if the words are mangled because the language only support ASCII. (I'm half a devil's advocate here: In almost all cases I'd call it "cheese", though for other reasons.)

Comment: @delnan Then there you have a perfect reason to include special characters if the language lets you. This is an opinion based question. My answer should be: if you're comfortable with it, then do it. I like coding in English, that's why I do it, but if otherwise I would like to code in Mandarin, and my team understand it, then I would be coding Mandarin, is a matter of choice. I also think that if your source will be read by other people not speaking German, `Cheese`  class will be better than `Käse` class for them.

Comment: @PauloBu As I said, I strongly prefer English names myself too. I actually think it's useless to harmful to not use English in code whenever possible, regardless of other circumstances. But (1) that's mainly my opinion, and (2) it's not always possible. One example (stolen from a Samsung employee working on Servo IIRC) would be implementing business rules based on Korean legalese: There's probably no good (let alone obvious) English translation, transliterating it into ASCII doesn't help *anyone* understand it, and a bad translation might be *harmful* in understanding the code.

Comment: As a native English speaker, I'm naturally nervous that Mandarin will become the de facto language of international discourse before I retire rather than after. As such, I'm *very* reluctant to go around telling foreigners that the only good practice is to do all programming in English regardless of intended audience. If I support such a practice then I'll regret it when it switches, but for the time being it is in fact accepted practice by many/most programmers...

Comment: @SteveJessop Worry not! If that happens then you can get a copy of Chinese for Dummies: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Chinese-For-Dummies-Wendy-Abraham/dp/047178897X

Comment: It's a simple question of who your _code's_ target audience is.  If you intend native speakers to be the only people reading or modifying your code, then by all means use UTF characters.  If not, try to stick to things that won't cause confusion for others when reading or editing.

Comment: @dstromberg: Projects fail badly when expectations at the start, later turn out to be wrong. So let's have "one language to bind them all" - even if that arguably changes in a couple of years. Besides - if I were an english native speaker I wouldn't know if I were too happy that everybody on this world now starts to write and speak my language full with errors & false friends and such, introducing them to my language forever. Maybe the Chinese are more intelligent than to allow that. Also keeping English for dummy programmers allows them to speak without others eavesdropping <tongue in cheek>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're using Python 3, given the tag.

It's good practice for your code to be clear and communicative. If the program you're writing is, for example, proprietary software developed by programmers who speak your language, then of course name the class Diário, and not Diario. There is no sense in murdering your own language and making things difficult to understand.

You can read [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#source-file-encoding), but its comments on encoding are primarily intended for programmers contributing to the Python standard library (which I'm guessing you're not). PEP8 is not nearly as strict as some make out - it simply insists on English for the standard library and then states that:

`Open source projects with a global audience are encouraged to adopt a similar policy.`

You should take this to mean that your code (and comments!) be in English unless you're very sure it won't be read by a wider audience. That's all the good practice you need to know about - err on the side of caution, and use English unless you're sure it's not necessary. Only you can decide what the best practice is in your case.

Comment: "PEP8 is not nearly as strict as some make out" -- specifically, PEP8 is the style guide for code distributed in CPython. Not (as some make out) the style guide for all Python code everywhere. Of course it's commonly used in other projects, since if you like GvR's language the chances are you're going to agree with a lot of his style too :-)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Python 2.7 won't allow that (will throw `SyntaxError`). Also, naming your variables, classes, or whatever in another language that is not English is a bad practice.

See [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer-better not. Longer answer-impossible in python 2.7 as it will give you a Syntax error, but python3 will allow you to do that, though it it is a very very very bad practice to do so. Not just in python, but in any language out there.

Comment: **Why** is it bad practice? Without supporting evidence this is just an opinion. We can leave Python 2 out of the picture here; it is not a syntax error in Python 3.

Comment: Of course you are free to do as you wish. However you should try to avoid using things that may potentially cause big issues in the future-from using tools that generate documentation, to involving other people in the project. Evidence-my previous job-I had to migrate databases which were created using a software written by an external company. The external company was from Romania, and so the entire database naming was in Romanian. Forget the fact that I had to learn a few hundred words in Romanian, I was considering suicide when we got to the encoding bit.

Comment: I didn't say I disagree it is bad practice. I am merely pointing out that your answer is not *providing any evidence* as to why it is bad practice.

Comment: And personal anecdotes are not evidence. :-) I'm trying to avoid this question becoming an opinion-fest. Let's keep answers factual here.

Comment: It is also very very very bad practice to write code that handles text (source code being a special case of text) that can't handle non-ASCII. So assuming that one cannot use non-ASCII characters because it's beyond your feeble documentation generation tools is hopefully over-conservative. But since personally I don't know off-hand what characters are correctly handled by the doctools *I* use, there's a precautionary principle that means I wouldn't use non-ASCII class names without at least testing the tools I rely on. e.g. I've had problems with `coverage` in Python 2 on UTF-8 source.

Comment: ... you'd hope that documentation tools and `coverage` and IDEs and whatever are fixed for Python 3. But I don't know, so to me an answer saying what does and doesn't work would be interesting and useful.